# DOM Element Virtual Values or Mapped Values

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 textboxes that make up an input for a text-shadow property, and are contained within a DIV like so:

```
<div id="shadow">
    <input type="number" min="-5" max="5" step="1" value="0" id="hshad" />
    <input type="number" min="-5" max="5" step="1" value="0" id="vshad" />
    <input type="number" min="0" max="20" step="1" value="0" id="bshad" />
    <input type="text" value="#000000" id="cshad" />
</div>
```

Right now, I manually combine the four inputs to get a desired css value. Something like this:

```
$('#elem').css('text-shadow', $('#hshad').val() + "px " + $('#vshad').val() + "px " + $('#bshad').val() + "px " + $('#cshad').val());
```

Is there a way I could 'map' these values to the value of `#shadow` as both a getter and a setter?

For example `$('#shadow').val()` would give me

`"0px 1px 5px #FFFFFF"`

And I could set the values of the four inputs by doing:

`$('#shadow').val("0px 1px 5px #FFFFFF")`

This is pretty much for the purpose (because I know you'll ask) of being able to loop through CSS rules and set form field values when editing a record that has pre-exiting rules. This all goes to a wicked WYSIWYG I'm making.

**EDIT**

Ok, so it's important for the sake of this question to pass back from `val()`. I'm looping through ~20-30 CSS rules, and don't want to have to get stumped on a single rule. I *could* just go back after the loop and break apart the value, but I was hoping to extend `val` and keep my code in a nice, tidy loop.

**Example**

My CSS to loop (as JSON object)"

```
{
    "top": "48px",
    "left": "59px",
    "width": "100px",
    "height": "100px",
    "font-family": "Oxygen",
    "font-size": "1em",
    "font-weight": "normal",
    "color": "rgb(51, 51, 51)",
    "text-shadow": "rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px 0px 0px",
    "background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
    "border-radius": "0px",
    "-moz-border-radius": "0px",
    "box-shadow": "none",
    "-moz-box-shadow": "none",
    "padding": "0px"
}
```

I give each form field a `data-prop` attribute for its associated CSS property like so:

```
<input type="text" data-prop="font-family" />
```

Then I would loop the rules like so

```
$.each(cssRules, function(name, value) {
  $('[data-prop=' + name + ']').val(value);
})
```

Nice, neat, and cozy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XCCgv/4/

```
$.valHooks.div = {

    get: function( elem ) {
        if( elem.id !== "shadow" ) return;

        return $.map( $("input", elem ), function (element,index) {
                return index === 3 ? element.value : element.value + "px"
        }).join(" ");

    },

    set: function( elem, value ) {
        if( elem.id !== "shadow" ) return;

        var inputs = $( "input", elem );

        $.each( value.split(" "), function( index, value ) {
            var val = parseFloat(value);
            inputs[index].value = isNaN(val) ? value : val;
        });

        return true;
    }

};
```

Edit: I saw your edit but I think you get the idea from here... you can check `$(elem).data()` in the valHook and call a different function depending on that. Here I am just checking for `.id === "shadow"`

Comment: Absolutely incredible. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @KyleMacey note that in the setter `return true` is to signal jQuery that the hook was successfull.. otherwise it tries to set a `.value` of `div` which might cause error in ie

Comment: Hmmm... would it be more conventional to return the element it's attached to for chaining functions? Ex: `$('#shadow').val('...').appendTo('...')`  I may be completely off base, and it doesn't matter to me but jw.

Comment: @KyleMacey it has nothing to do with chaining, the `.val` function calls the hook inside itself and returns `this` no matter what. It doesn't return what the hook returned

Comment: Makes sense. Never been this deep in JQ, so forgive my misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = [];
$('div#shadow input').filter(function(index, val) {
   index != 3 ? value.push(this.value + 'px') : value.push(this.value);
});

console.log(value.join(' '));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/uqcA3/3/)**

Comment: That gets me on a single instance, but I can't loop through all my inputs with that syntax. Trying to stick to `val()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a custom plugin or function. I'll do a function for simplicity.

```
function getShadow() {
    return $.map( $("#shadow input"), function (element,index) {
        return index === 3 ? element.value : element.value + "px"
    }).join(" ");
}

console.log(getShadow());
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/XCCgv/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jQuery function which you can use as getter/setter for your case:

```
$.fn.customVal = function(val){
     if(!val){
       //getter
       var value = [];
       $('input',$(this)).filter(function(index, val) {
            value.push(this.value);
       }); 

        value = $.map(value,function(elem,index){
           return index != 3 ? elem + 'px' : elem;
        }); 
       return value.join(' '); 
     }else{
       //setter
       var parts = val.split("px");
       $('input',$(this)).each(function(index, val) {
            $(this).val($.trim(parts[index]));
       });  

    }
};

alert($('#shadow').customVal());

$('#shadow').customVal("0px 1px 5px #FFFFFF");

alert($('#shadow').customVal());
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/VQrZV/1/)
    ​